# Why cos(a-b) =cos(a+(-b))?

Tags: trigonometry

Why sin(A-B) is same as sin[A+(-B)]?
i mean,we have derived the formula  of  sin(a+b) geometrically in  a uniqe  way..then how can we replace +b with -b in identity?
To sum up, doesn't changing the sign of variable in a identity ,change the identity itself specially when we are dealing with coordinate system?
( NOTE- I KNOW THAT sin(a-b)  yeilds us same formula as sin[a+(-b)] geometrically too)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the cosine. We simply have $a-b=a+(-b)$

Comment: This has nothing to do with trigonometry, simply $a-b = a+(-b)$

Comment: Instead subtracting a number feel free to add its negative.

Answer (score 1):

It's more fundamental than that. We have
$$
a-b=a+(-b)
$$
because that's the definition of the binary operation $-$. And since those two are equal, clearly they must have the same sine and the same cosine.

As for why we can use the formula you derived for $\sin(a+b)$ to evaluate $\sin(a+(-b))$, that's just a matter of variable names. Ignore the meaning of $-$ for a second and consider $-b$ a single symbol. Then you will see that the name of a variable, whether it's $b$ or $-b$, changes nothing of the argument, and the formula that pops out in the end of just as valid.

Comment: Well.. I know that subtraction is addition of negative nos but can you tell me how can we put - b in geometric proof of cos(a+b), else a diagram which can prove both identity at the same time would be appreciated please help me